# replacing files in a zip file, which is stored as bytes in the database

Tags: java, mysql, zip, arrays

I am currently working on a web application. the database table that i am trying to access has the following columns:

`archive_pk` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`archive` mediumblob NOT NULL,

`checksum` varchar(32) NOT NULL,

user1 uploads a zipped file(an eclipse project) which is then converted to a bytes and stored under the 'archive' column, the archive_pk is auto generated and the checksum is calculated using the java.security.MessageDigest library. (MessageDigest.digest(bytes) , #bytes being the byte stream representation of the zip file).

user2 gets the archive from the database using the archive_pk. he wants to replace the content of some of the files in the archive (content of *.java file(s)) . I am using the java.util.zip.* module to try and access specific zip entries and replace their content. But the data ends up getting corrupted everytime.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: How are you replacing content in zip archives? Some code is welcome.

Comment: @NickolayOlshevsky - i am not able to do that. I do not know how to go about it.